# Issue with changing specific table cell content background

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a table that once created and one animal is randomly selected to go into a cell from an array, the animal can be selected from a dropdown menu and will change the color of all the elements in the table containing this animal.

Here is a link to my work I have uploaded, the function for this color change for cat specifically is on line 149. My issue is once I select cat in the dropdown menu I get nothing.?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/VonDutch/p7zcnv8f/2/)

> Target code:

```
function catColor() {
    var tdTags = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var searchText = "cat";

    for (var i = 0; i < tdTags.length; i++) {
        if (tdTags[i].textContent == searchText) {
            document.tdTags[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Down vote before people finish typing question...coding need patience dude, helping as well

Comment: Im sorry if I annoyed anyone, I'm quite new to this site and topic.

Comment: Don't worry, nothing link with you @ClutchBleu. Some user of Stackoverflow needs more empathy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
cat.addEventListener("select", function() { // WRONG !!!!!
    catColor();
})
```

Do this:

```
var animalSelect = document.getElementById("dropDown");
animalSelect .addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
    var selectedAnimal = ev.currentTarget.value;
    console.log(selectedAnimal);
})
```

Also, don't do this:

```
document.tdTags[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue"; // WRONG !!!!!
```

Do this:

```
tdTags[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I just realised I'm referring to document twice!

Comment: You're welcome. As an advice: check every step in the execution; don't assume you are executing a function if you cannot stop with `debugger` or print with `console.log()`, use `debugger` and `console.log()` in previous steps (the event listener in this case) to check them. Keep learning!